# Neo4J Join style relationship

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to learn about Neo4J; and i'm totally scratching my head.
Basically I have the following cypher query, which is selecting some nodes from my graph based on a few regex queries, which are purposely up to 4 links/nodes apart.

What I want to be able to do is return paths and other nodes, which connect these nodes.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE any(prop in keys(n) where n[prop] =~ "(?i)4567890123456789-0.*")
OR any(prop in keys(n) where n[prop] =~ "(?i)3456789012345678.*")
OR any(prop in keys(n) where n[prop] =~ "(?i)1234567890123456.*")

MATCH path = (s)-[r*0..4]-(f)
 // Here
RETURN path, n
```

What I think I need is something like

```
MATCH path = (s)-[r*0..4]-(f)
// WHERE s IN(n) AND f IN(n)
RETURN path, n
```

I'm probably being a massive idiot here...

**Update**
I've kind of managed to get it working like this:

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE any(prop in keys(n) where n[prop] =~ "(?i)4567890123456789-0.*")
OR any(prop in keys(n) where n[prop] =~ "(?i)3456789012345678.*")
OR any(prop in keys(n) where n[prop] =~ "(?i)1234567890123456.*")
WITH collect(n) as valid
MATCH path = (s)-[r*0..3]-(f)
WHERE s in valid
AND f in valid
RETURN path
```

But now I need to also return dangling nodes too, haha :) Fun

Comment: Hello! Please be more specific about your problem. What your current dataset looks like and what results you are trying to reach?

Comment: What is a "dangling node"? Also, are your regular expressions always the same?

Comment: Hey guys!
Thanks for the response, it's hard to give too much context without the worlds longest post - I didn't feel the data was particularly relevant as I was talking semantically about how to do the equivalent of a SQL style join.

By dangling node; in the above example; I'm trying to find paths between the nodes returned from the original match.  If there are are no paths, I consider that node 'dangling'.  It turns out that if i do a 'graph' query rather than 'rest' against the api, I do also return nodes.  Subsequently - I think I'm all good now.  But thanks for the replies!